# Minimal API BindAsync doesn't work .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, minimal-apis

I was trying to bind data manually using BindAsync and I followed the Microsoft docs and here is the link : [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#custom-binding). But it doesn't work with me.

I have the following simple code

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/Test",  ([FromQuery] Student student) =>
{
    return  $"Student: {student.Id}, {student.Name}";
}).WithTags("Student");
```

and here is class Student

```
public class Student
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public static ValueTask<Student> BindAsync(HttpContext context, ParameterInfo parameter)
     {
         string name = context.Request.Query["name"];
         int.TryParse(context.Request.Query["id"], out var id);
         var result = new Student
         {
             Name = name,
             Id = id
         };
         return ValueTask.FromResult<Student>(result);
     }
 }
```

I have 2 problems

1. I get an error that **"public static bool TryParse"** was not found
2. Even if I add simple TryParse in student class like this

```
public static bool TryParse(string value, out Student student)
 {
     student = new();
     return true;
 }
```

I still got an error message from the endpoint **"Message": "Required parameter "Student student" was not provided from query string."** even though I have sent it using swagger and the URL is like this **"https://localhost:5001/student?id=7&name=myName"**

Comment: Why are you using BindAsync at all? `GET` uses query binding already, there's no need for BindAsync. HTTP GET doesn't have a body.

Comment: You are right, but when I don't add FromQuery it doesn't show the object student on swagger but if I directly hit the end point it return the result. So, do you know how to show it on swagger? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Swagger isn't the API, nor does it affect its operation. It's unclear what you even mean by Swagger - the OpenAPI document, or the *Swashbuckle* or NSwag UI built from the document? Post the actual code that caused the OpenAPI, Swashbuckle or NSwag problem.

Comment: yea I mean the Swashbuckle UI. `app..UseSwagger()
.UseSwaggerUI(opt =>
{
    opt.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyProject");
    opt.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});` Here is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need [FromQuery] and your URL does not contain '/Test'
Here is an example: "https://localhost:7110/Test?Id=7&Name=Test"
Working solution:

```
using System.Reflection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/Test",  (Student student) => $"Student: {student.Id}, {student.Name}").WithTags("Student");

app.Run();

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; init; }
    public string Name { get; init; }
    

    public static ValueTask<Student> BindAsync(HttpContext context, ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        string name = context.Request.Query["name"];
        int.TryParse(context.Request.Query["id"], out var id);
        var result = new Student
        {
            Name = name,
            Id = id
        };
        return ValueTask.FromResult<Student>(result);
    }
    public static bool TryParse(string value, out Student student)
    {
        student = new();
        return true;
    }
}
```